# How to show a floating message in windows phone (Android Toasts)

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

How can I implement the behaviour of an Android Toast, that is, a floating message that is auto dismissed after some seconds without requiring a user interaction?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [toast notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779727.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, could you provide a snipplet to show a simple message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows Phone there are [toasts available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779727.aspx#showing_toast_on_the_lock_screen). They can be showed on demand or be scheduled. They are shown at the top of the screen and dissapear after a while. A sample toast showed on demand can look like this:

```cs
ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;
XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
XmlNodeList textElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
textElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("MyApp"));
textElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Message"));
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(new ToastNotification(toastXml));
```

You will find more information [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465448.aspx).

NOTE that the code above is for WP8.1 RunTime and Universal apps. If you are looking for *Silverlight* example, take a look st [ShellToast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltoast(v=vs.105).aspx) and [tutorial at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465448.aspx).